# SQL - is it possible to use a value in a different row to update another row if conditions are met?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Suppose I have a table that looks like this:

```
col_1 |  col_2    
x     |   y    
null  |   y    
a     |   b
```

Is is possible for me to change the null in `col_1` to `x` if `y = y` in a query?

I'm trying to do this in SQL. I think I need to use CASE clause, but not sure how to go about this.

Comment: What do you mean _"if y = y"_. There's no situation in this table where that is the case and `y == y`.

Comment: Your logic is incomplete. How do you know which rows to compare? Are you specifically comparing the rows in order (row 1 with row 2, then row 2 with row 3)? Or are you comparing rows where they share the same value in col_2? If so, what do you want to happen if there is also another row with `(col_1 = 'z', col_2 = 'y')`? Or perhaps you mean something else entirely? You need to give a more complete and detailed example of what you are and are not trying to do.

Comment: Where the values in col_2 equal each other.  The real life example is that I have a table containing data from multiple sources.  Sometimes col_1 is populated with identifiers, sometimes col_2 is.  So when col_2 match I want the query to return x y for both rows 1 and 2.

Comment: @LauraHowes - But can there ever be more than 2 rows with the same value in `col_2`?  For example, if you added the row `'z', 'y'` to your data?  If that is possible, how would you know what to change the `NULL` to?  `'x'` or `'z'`?

Comment: Sounds like a normalisation issue. For every value in `col_2`, you want `col_1` to be the same. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the self join with the table itself and update the row if match is found.

```
update tablename set
 cp.col_1 = pp.Col_1
 from tablename cp,
 tablename pp where
 cp.col_1 = null and
 cp.col_2 = pp.col_2
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
UPDATE MyTable x1
    set col_1 = 
    (SELECT col_1 
     FROM MyTable x2 
     WHERE x2.col_2 = x1.col_2 AND x2.col_1 IS NOT NULL
           AND rownum = 1)
    WHERE x1.col_1 IS NULL
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0ba92/2)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it but x value if not null have to be the same for same y value

1. use a cursor
2. select all distinct y value in temporary table with their x value
3. iterate on each row and set your x value if column is null

the performance is slow but it is simply working